# Android potential parallel read/write issue

Tags: android

The Android documentation states that "one activity in your application might be instantiated multiple times". Let's now assume that:

- I use onStart() to save state in permanent storage
- I use onStop() to load state from permanent storage

Now let's assume that I have 2 instances of my main activity (inst1 & inst2) and that I have the following call sequence:

1. inst1.onStart()
2. inst2.onStart()
3. inst1.onStop()
4. inst2.onStop()
5. inst1.onStart()

Then, this would mean that instance #1 would end up loading the state of instance #2.

Is this a possible scenario ? If yes, how can this be avoided ?

**Edit**: actually, it looks like this scenario is not possible since you cannot possibly have 2 instances of the same activity in the "running" state at the same time.

Comment: You should use onPause() and onResume().

Comment: @Simon: I'm afraid the Android documentation states that storing in permanent storage should be done in onStop() and not in onResume().

Answer (score 2):

If by "permanent storage" you mean shared preferences or files, then yes. Otherwise if you are using `onSaveInstanceState`, then no. As the method name says, it's a per-instance mechanism. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29):

*"Called to retrieve **per-instance** state from an activity before being killed so that the state can be restored in onCreate(Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) (the Bundle populated by this method will be passed to both).*
...
*The default implementation takes care of most of the UI **per-instance** state"*

Comment: The issue is that onRestoreInstanceState() is not always called. For example, exiting your application by using the BACK button and starting it again will not invoke it...

Comment: It's not calling onRestoreInstanceState because in the case of closing the app there is no state to be saved/restored. It's a clean start the next time you open it. You could save some stuff to your preferences or the database when onStop is getting called and restore it the next time you start the activity.

Comment: That's because `onSaveInstanceState` is intended to save state when the activity is killed by the system, or it is destroyed because a configuration change has occured. If it's the user exiting the app, then you have to find other means of saving state.

Comment: @MisterSmith : sure, but then the problem I'm describing still applies, ie: assuming that I'm reading/writing to permanent storage in onStart()/onStop(), how can I make sure that an activity instance does not overwrite the data previously stored by another instance ?

Comment: With shared preferences, for instance, you can use a combined key such as "<instance part><attribute name>", where <instance part> is a unique ID for that instance. But I can't understand yor intent: assuming you manage to save state for each activity, after both are closed, which one are you restoring next time?

Comment: @MisterSmith: I should have mentioned that the "state" I want to persist is the array that backs an ArrayAdapter. In that case, it looks like the scenario I'm describing is not possible since you cannot have inst1.onStart() followed by inst2.onStart(). What you can have is inst1.onStart() -> inst1.onStop() -> inst2.onStart() and in that case the state is going to the same across all instances.

Comment: Yes you can have two `onStart` calls. Change `onStart` for `onResume` and `onStop` for `onPause` and your previous comment will be true.

Comment: @MisterSmith: are you sure about this ? The onStart() javadoc states that "onStart() is called after onCreate() or after onRestart() when the activity had been stopped, but is now again being displayed to the user". Since you can only have one activity instance displayed to the user on the screen, how would it be possible to have onStart() called 2 times ?

Comment: Some dialog-like activities will allow the activity in the background to be still visible. If your activity is neither dialog-like nor traslucent, then no.

Comment: @MisterSmith : this makes senses, however do we agree that if inst1 and inst2 are two instances of the SAME non-dialog activity, then it's not possible to have inst1.onStart() followed by inst2.onStart() ? Even if this activity was translucent, I don't see how 2 instances could end up on top of each other...

Comment: If you were starting one from the another, and you were applying a screen transition (such as slide-in), then both would be visible at the same time. (Don't make me test when the lifecycle calls happen XD)